# Not using $ in literals with x86

Tags: x86, att

In AT&T's syntax for x86 one must use $ to indicate literals. Does that mean that if I specify a single number the program will go look for the data contained in that memory adress?

For example:

```
movl 1,%eax
```

Would this try to move the data in the 0x00000001 memory section to a register? I know it will most likely fail when looking for it, I'm just curious.

Comment: "Would this try to move the data in the 0x00000001 memory section to a register?" Yes, you're right.

Comment: Ok, I was just doubtful that I had to put the brackets in there to specify it's a memory reference, like 1(,,) (to just ommit the base, offset and scale values)